# Comparar subconsultas

Tags: mysql, sql

Con esta query pretendo buscar todos los clientes que tengan todas las conexiones dadas de baja

```
       SELECT
          (SELECT COUNT(*) 
               FROM conexiones con 
               WHERE con.cliente = cl.id ) 
          AS total_conexiones, 
          (SELECT COUNT(*) 
               FROM conexiones con 
               WHERE con.cliente = cl.id AND con.alta != '0000-00-00' AND con.baja != '0000-00-00') 
          AS baja_conexiones,
          cx.id,
          cl.razonsocial 
       FROM
          conexiones AS cx 
          LEFT JOIN
             clientes AS cl 
             ON cl.id = cx.cliente 
       WHERE
          total_conexiones = baja_conexiones
```

El problema me viene el la condición where donde me dice que el alias de las subconsultas `total_conexiones` y `baja_conexiones` no existen.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? y ¿cómo se podría replantear esta query?

Comment: ¿Nos pasas el dataset para comprobar la consulta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que si quieres validar subconsultas a nivel de condicional con el `WHERE` lo debes hacer poniendo todas tus fuentes como `FROM` dicho de otra manera, a grandes rasgos lo que hace una subquery es seleccionar datos específicos de una tabla o entidad, dicho esto tu consulta deberia quedar de la siguiente manera

```
       SELECT
          total_conexiones.*,
          baja_conexiones.*,
          cx.id,
          cl.razonsocial 
       FROM
          conexiones AS cx,
          LEFT JOIN clientes AS cl ON cl.id = cx.cliente,
          (SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM conexiones con 
           WHERE con.cliente = cl.id ) total_conexiones,
          (SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM conexiones con 
           WHERE con.cliente = cl.id AND con.alta != '0000-00-00' AND con.baja != '0000-00-00') baja_conexiones 
       WHERE
          total_conexiones = baja_conexiones
```

De hecho dentro de la propia documentacion de MySQL te dice que la forma correcta de hacerla es la siguiente

```
       SELECT
          total_conexiones.*,
          baja_conexiones.*,
          cx.id,
          cl.razonsocial 
       FROM
          conexiones AS cx,
          (SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM conexiones con 
           WHERE con.cliente = cl.id AND con.alta != '0000-00-00' AND con.baja != '0000-00-00') baja_conexiones,
           LEFT JOIN clientes AS cl ON cl.id = cx.cliente 
       WHERE
          (SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM conexiones con 
           WHERE con.cliente = cl.id ) = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM conexiones con 
           WHERE con.cliente = cl.id AND con.alta != '0000-00-00' AND con.baja != '0000-00-00')
```

Lo que yo haria cambia un poco lo que tu hiciste, mas que nada por la logica y para evitar errores en asignación.

```
SELECT
    total_conexiones.*,
    baja_conexiones.*,
    cx.id,
    cl.razonsocial 
FROM
    conexiones AS cx,
    LEFT JOIN clientes AS cl ON cl.id = cx.cliente,
    (SELECT id,COUNT(*) as conteo 
     FROM conexiones con 
     WHERE con.cliente = cl.id ) total_conexiones
     INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT id,COUNT(*) as conteo 
     FROM conexiones con 
     WHERE con.cliente = cl.id AND con.alta != '0000-00-00' AND con.baja != '0000-00-00') baja_conexiones ON total_conexiones.id = baja_conexiones.id  
WHERE total_conexiones.conteo = baja_conexiones.conteo
```

En esta ultima si te das cuento hago un `INNER JOIN` sobre las dos subqueries para obtener todos los datos que coincidan en el punto exacto en que coiciden y al final nada mas valido los conteos de ambas partes.

Al final básicamente lo que le estas diciendo es que de `total_conexiones` te obtenga el conteo, de `baja_conexiones` igual y de las otras tablas te obtenga id y razon social, esto lo puedes leer mas claramente en [MySQL Subquery](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/) , [MySQL Subqueries](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/subqueries/index.php) , [13.2.11 Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html)

Answer (score 1):

La forma rápida es poner la condición en `HAVING` y no en `WHERE`:

```
HAVING total_conexiones = baja_conexiones
```

Si te interesan más los clientes que el conteo, ésta consulta es más simple:

```
SELECT *
  FROM clientes cl
  WHERE ( SELECT count(1)
                -count(if(     cx.alta != '0000-00-00' 
                           and cx.baja != '0000-00-00'
                         , 1
                         , 0
                         )
                       ) 
            FROM conexiones cx
            WHERE cx.cliente = cl.id
        ) = 0
```

Usando una *consulta escalar* para la condición. El primer `count` es para todas las conexiones, el segundo haciendo una *agregación condicional* cuenta si la conexión ha sido dada de baja. Si la resta de todas menos las dadas de baja es cero, entonces es uno de los clientes que buscas.